# Can't get the necessary date

Tags: swift, date

I am trying to get the difference between dates in days. I have a problem translating dates to the desired format.

```swift
func daysBefore(_ date: String) -> Int {

    let currentDate = Date()
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()

    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd.mm.YYYY"

    guard let nextDate = dateFormater.date(from: date) else {
        return 0
    }

    return currentDate.interval(ofComponent: .day, fromDate: nextDate)
}

extension Date {

    func interval(ofComponent comp: Calendar.Component, fromDate date: Date) -> Int {

        let currentCalendar = Calendar.current

        guard let start = currentCalendar.ordinality(of: comp, in: .era, for: date) else { return 0 }
        guard let end = currentCalendar.ordinality(of: comp, in: .era, for: self) else { return 0 }

        return end - start
    }
}

daysBefore("22.09.2019")
```

When I convert the date from String to Date in:

```swift
    let currentDate = Date()
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()

    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd.mm.YYYY"

    guard let nextDate = dateFormater.date(from: date) else {
        return 0
    }
```

I always get something like: 2018-12-22 21:09:00 +0000.

But expected(in example): 22.09.2019.

Comment: Your format should be `dd.MM.yyyy `, `m` is minutes, and `Y` is for a Year in "Week of Year" based calendars (probably not what you're using).

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not expect that everything is so simple, I need a rest :)

Comment: A better solution is to avoid using `dateFormat`. Use `dateStyle` instead so the result is formatted correctly based on the user's locale.